# Pronunciation of 日 in compound words

Tags: pronunciation

I learnt from my teacher that the days of the month from 1 to 10 use kun and irregular pronunciations:
一日: ついたち (irregular)
二日: ふつか (kun)
三日: みっか (kun)
...
十日: とおか (kun)

But for words like 一日目, 二日間 and 三日間後, what would be the correct pronunciation and the rules for this?
I heard 一日目 is いちにちめ and 三日間後 is みっかかんあと. Is this correct?

Comment: tuitati is only "irregular" because the kanji are ateji. tuitati is from tukitati (月立ち), the rising moon which occurs at the start of a month, ie the 1st day of a new moon.

Comment: On a side note, all days ending in '4' are also irregular, and use ~よっか. So the 14th is じゅうよっか, the 24th is にじゅうよっか, even though all the other days >10 switch over to ~にち.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you've learned is correct.  The first ten days "always" (that is, I've never found otherwise) use the kun readings, except for `一日` as you noted with `一日目`.  Also, for "later/after", the pronunciation is `ご`, not `あと`.

> - 今日は誕生日の四日前（よっかまえ）です。　→　Today is 4 days before my birthday.
> - 九日間（ここのかかん）かかった台風　→　A typhoon that lasted for 9 days
> - クリスマスの六日後（むいかご）は大【おお】晦【みそ】日【か】です。　→　6 days after Christmas is New Year's Eve (Ōmisoka). / The 6th day after Christmas is New Year's Eve.

Comment: "always"? Quote: 「トハヰカニ、ケフハウヅキノヒトヒカハ　マダキモシツルコロモガヘカナ」(『今昔物語集』, volume 28, chapter 12). Here ヒトヒ (一日) means the 1st of 卯月 (4th lunar month).

Comment: That's why I put it in quotes.

Comment: @Dono: Nitpicking: istrasci did not claim that 一日 is always read as ついたち, so your comment is technically not a counterexample.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: You are mistaken. The claim is quote: "The first ten day "always" (that is, I've never found otherwise) use the _kun readings, except for 一日_." 一日 has the kun reading ひとひ as cited with a real quotation from literature. Hence, this is clear counterexample disproving the claim.

Comment: @Dono: My point is that istrasci claimed something always happens except for 一日, but he did not claim anything about 一日.  For example, “f(x) is positive except when x=0” does not technically imply “f(x) is not positive when x=0.”  (And I said that this is a nitpicking.)

Comment: @Dono: Nitpicking continued - Then your example didn't disprove anything; in fact, it further **proved** it because the quote said "use the kun readings" and you provided another kun reading.

Comment: @istrasci Nitpicking the nitpicking: Quote again: "The first ten days "always" (that is, I've never found otherwise) use the kun readings, except for 一日 as you noted with 一日目." Hence, the claim is 一日 does NOT use (or have) a kun reading "as noted with 一日目", which is an on reading. 一日 has a kun reading of hitohi, so your claim of "always" is disproved.

Comment: @Dono:  [Hence, the claim is 一日 does NOT use (or have) a kun reading "as noted with 一日目"].  Wrong.  The claim is that 一日 does not ALWAYS USE the kun reading.  ついたち is a kun reading, is it not?

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you guys liked nitpicking...

Comment: You mention that "Except for "later/after", the pronunciation is `ご`, not `あと`", but in your example you showed that `六日後`, meaning six days after, was pronounced as `むいかご`. Also, is it normal to not put `間` after `N日` when saying `N days before/after` ?

Comment: @小太郎: `ご`: edited wording in my answer for clarity. As for not putting `間`, `間` indicates the length of the period and puts focus on it.  For the "4 days before"/"6 days after", you're not really focusing on the whole 4/6 day interval, just which day it is.  I'm not 100% positive that you *can't* put it in, but it feels wrong to me.

Comment: ついたち　is not a kunyomi, unless you believe that つい is a kunyomi reading for　一 and たち is one for　日.  It is an "ateji" reading: an arbitrarily assigned reading for a kanji or kanji compound. One notable ateji example is 缶 whose meaning is "can" (as in tin container). The reading is かん. That is from English; it is an assigned kanji for a foreign loanword.

Comment: @Kaz: But the "ateji" reading itself is kunyomi, as Dono explained in his opening comment about 月立ち.  So that doesn't count?

Comment: @Kaz: You are right in that ついたち cannot be decomposed into kun readings of individual kanji letters.  But ついたち is a kun reading of the whole word 一日.  A kun reading of a word which cannot be decomposed into kun readings of individual kanji letters is called 熟字訓, and ついたち is an example of it.