# Can I pronounce　十三日 as じゅうみっか?

Tags: pronunciation, readings, numbers

I wonder if both prounciations of 十三日 are accepted?

- じゅうさんにち
- じゅうみっか

The reasons I am asking are these:

1. Windows IME seems to accept it
2. 十四日　is pronouncecd as じゅうよっか, matching the pronunciation of 四日, which is よっか, but my textbook says 十三日 should be pronounced as じゅうさんにち

At the same time, both Google Translate and my dictionary (Weblio) gives only the first pronunciation (じゅうさんにち).

1. [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E5%8D%81%E4%B8%89%E6%97%A5%0A&op=translate)
2. [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8D%81%E4%B8%89%E6%97%A5)

Comment: 参考:  [Do we use odd day pronunciations outside of calendar ranges?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/7014/78)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I pronounce 十三日 as じゅうみっか?

*Can* you?  Yes.  You could also pronounce it as *wagawaga boom tash*, or as *fweeeEEEEEE gobble gobble*.  However, none of these are likely to be understood by Japanese speakers to mean "the thirteenth day of the month".

> Windows IME seems to accept it

The Windows IME is probably parsing this as じゅう + みっか, not as じゅうみっか as a single term.

In fact, typing this here just now, I see that the IME has zero kanji conversion candidates for the whole kana string じゅうみっか -- only for the pieces of it, with じゅう as one sub-string and みっか as the other.  If I instead enter the kana string じゅうさんにち, I do indeed see 十三日 as a conversion candidate for the entire kana string, not just a part of it.

> 十四日 is pronounced as じゅうよっか, matching the pronunciation of 四日, which is よっか

一日 is another irregular reading for dates, ついたち and never いちにち.  Other dates up through "the tenth" use the native Japanese-derived readings.  二十日 for dates is also native-derived, and is read as はつか, never にじゅうにち.

All of the "fours" in dates are strange for some reason, related to obscure details of historical development.  This holds true for 四日 (only よっか, never よんにち or しにち), 十四日 (only じゅうよっか, never じゅうよんいち or じゅうしにち), and 二十四日 (only にじゅうよっか, never にじゅうよんにち or にじゅうしにち).

Otherwise, other dates from "the eleventh" through to "the thirty-first" are read with the expected 音読【おんよ】み: 十一日【じゅういちにち】、二十五日【にじゅうごにち】、三十一日【さんじゅういちにち】.

Comment: `You could also pronounce it as wagawaga boom tash, or as fweeeEEEEEE gobble gobble`  +1 just for that.  

Comment: How do you type kanji with the hiragana on top?

Comment: @user71207, when you click **Comment** to post a comment on an answer or question, there should be the **Add Comment** button on the right, and a **help** link just under that.  If you click the **help**, you get a blue text frame that appears below the comment text field.  In that blue text frame, click the **Learn more about formatting...** link to see [this page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).  Scroll down to the [**Japanese Language Extensions** section](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/editing-help#mainbar) for more about **furigana**.

Comment: (continued) @user71207, for furigana formatting in specific, see [this post](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/807#807).

Comment: "never にじゅうよんにち", not so, see for example https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/24%E6%97%A5. It's formal and limited in usage, though.

Comment: @dainichi, those are all 旧暦, so not in modern usage, no?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi, not necessarily. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%E6%9C%8824%E6%97%A5 "1月24日（いちがつにじゅうよっか、**いちがつにじゅうよんにち**）は**グレゴリオ暦**で年始から24日目"

Comment: @dainichi: フム、興味深いですね、こういう不規則なところ。 FWIW, I've never encountered the ～よんにち variants. That said, it seems like [some native speakers may instead feel that the ～よっか variants are odd.](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1187012321) I wonder if this is an area of the language that is currently undergoing a shift in usage?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi, Interesting... I've encountered にじゅうよんにち only in deliberately clear/formal/affected speech, and I thought everybody would say にじゅうよっか when speaking casually. I would be interesting to know the age/location of the person asking that question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is only pronounced as じゅうさんにち